# rails: multiple controller actions on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i got a simple rails app for browser bookmarks. 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45WFO.png) 
a bookmark, seen on the top, is a folder that contains the subcategory folders in the left sidebar. 
 when clicking a folder on the left one gets the bookmarks listing of the folder. i.e. a bookmarks#index with params. same is folder#index with params on the left and top. how can i render all the 3 controller action on one page?

Comment: You can use partials. Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: @user9675688 checkout the given answer below, i believe it will be helpful for you, let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely render to a common page from different actions, see the example:-
 in `bookmarks_controller.rb`

```
def index
  #do your stuffs
  render "path_of_comman_page",locals: {x: "foo", y: "bar"}
end
```

in `folder_controller.rb`

```
def index
  #do your stuffs
  render "path_of_comman_page",locals: {x: "foo", y: "bar"}
end
```

So here by you will be able to access all locals variable at your comman page. like `x, y`
path_of_comman_page can be for example `/bookmarks/listings` which means you are rendering data to `bookmarks controller listings.html.erb`

Alternative it can be done by common partial for example

```
def index
  #do your stuffs...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render partial: "listings/listing", locals: {x: "foo", y: "bar"}}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i want it like this, somehow with js. maybe it's possible with a controller too ... 
folders/index.haml

```
.container_top
- @folders.each do |f|
  - if f.is_rootparent?
    -# send ajax to fetch subcategory folders!
    =link_to folder_path(parent: f), remote: true do
      .bookmark_vertical
        %p = f.title
.container_left
  #appendsubcategoryfoldershere
```